# Pagination using Parse and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

I have been trying to look at various other questions for help however I cannot seem to be able to find a solution.

OnScrollListener that I am using: https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e

`rvHome.addOnScrollListener(new MainRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page) {
                fetchPosts(page);
            }
        });`

```
public void fetchOfflinePosts() {
    offlineListPosts = db.getAllPosts();

    for (Post post : offlineListPosts) {
        listPosts.add(post);
    }

    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void loadPosts() {

    if (ConnectivityHelper.isConnected(getContext())) {
        db.deleteAllPosts();
        listPosts.clear();
        fetchPosts(0);
    } else {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

}

public void fetchPosts(int skip) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> findPostsRequest = new ParseQuery<>("Post");
    findPostsRequest.setSkip(skip);
    findPostsRequest.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    findPostsRequest.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> posts, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject _post : posts) {
                    final Post post = new Post();

                    String objectId = _post.getObjectId();
                    String username;
                    String imageUrl;                      

                    if (_post.getString("username") != null) {
                        username = _post.getString("username");
                    } else {
                        username = "";
                    }

                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> findProfilePicQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
                    findProfilePicQuery.whereEqualTo("username", username);
                    findProfilePicQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {

                            if (e == null) {
                                for (ParseUser user : users) {

                                    if (user.getParseFile("profilePic") != null) {
                                        post.setProfilePicUrl(user.getParseFile("profilePic").getUrl());
                                    } else {
                                        post.setProfilePicUrl("");
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    if (_post.getParseFile("photo") != null) {
                        imageUrl = _post.getParseFile("photo").getUrl();
                    } else {
                        imageUrl = "";
                    }

                    post.setObjectId(objectId);
                    post.setUsername(username);
                    post.setImageUrl(imageUrl);

                    db.addPost(post);
                }

                fetchOfflinePosts();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

By using the code above I can get the RecyclerView to load more items once the last item is reached but the posts fetched are the same as the ones I have already got. I know I'm getting something really simple wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of Pagination and Refresh data with Parse:

```
    @Override
    public void onVideosRequested(final int categoryId, final boolean isRefresh, final int page) {
        if (!isRefresh && page == 0) {
            mView.showIndicator();
        }
        ParseQuery<ParseVideo> query = ParseVideo.generateGetVideosByCategoryQuery(categoryId, page, CategoryFragment.VIDEOS_PER_PAGE);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseVideo>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseVideo> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (!isRefresh) {
                    if (page == 0) {
                        mView.hideIndicator();
                    }
                } else {
                    mView.showHideRefreshLayout(false);
                }
                if (e == null) {
                    if (objects != null && objects.size() > 0) {
                        List<ParseVideo> mList = cleanData(objects);
                        List<ParseVideo> mVideos = DashboardActivity.mVideos.get(categoryId);
                        if (page == 0) {
                            mVideos.clear();
                            mVideos.addAll(mList);
                        } else {
                            mVideos.addAll(mList);
                        }
                        if (objects.size() < CategoryFragment.VIDEOS_PER_PAGE) {
                            mView.isLoadMoreAvailable(false);
                        } else {
                            mView.isLoadMoreAvailable(true);
                        }
                        DashboardActivity.mIndexes.put(categoryId, page);
                        mView.onVideosReceived(mList.size(), page);
                    } else {
                        mView.isLoadMoreAvailable(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    mView.onDefaultError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public List<ParseVideo> cleanData(List<ParseVideo> data) {
        List<ParseVideo> mList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ParseVideo pv : data) {
            if (pv != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pv.getName()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pv.getId())) {
                mList.add(pv);
            }
        }
        return mList;
    }
```

In ui set default variables for `pagination` and `refresh`:

```
private int currentPage = 0;
private boolean isLoadMoreAvailable = true;
```

And make your call:

```
mController.onVideosRequested(mId, false, currentPage);
```

And `onLoadMore`:

```
if (isLoadMoreAvailable) {
     mController.onVideosRequested(mId, false, currentPage + 1);
}
```

The tricky part with `onLoadMore` and `Refresh` together is when you refresh your data you have to reset your `scrollListeners` total and previous counts to keep `loadMore` still available.

```
mHidingScrollListener.setPreviousTotal(0);
mHidingScrollListener.setTotalItemCount(0);
```

Finally here's the `parse query`:

```
public static ParseQuery<ParseVideo> generateGetVideosByCategoryQuery(int categoryId, int page, int displayLimit) {
        ParseQuery<ParseVideo> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseVideo.class);
        query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.IS_DELETED, false);
        query.addDescendingOrder(ParseConstants.CREATED_At);
        if (categoryId != ParseConstants.CATEGORY_ID_HOME) {
            query.whereEqualTo(CATEGORY_ID, categoryId);
        }
        query.setLimit(displayLimit);
        query.setSkip(page * displayLimit);
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out now.

Comment: if you've problem about implementation we can discuss.